# Jmeter continue read multiple lines with multiple users

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, test-plan

I'm working on a load test using JMeter(4.0)
And I'm trying to insert some record by the CSV data.

The CSV data like:

```
Ref1,Value1 <- First Loop, User 1
Ref1,Value2 <- First Loop, User 2
Ref1,Value3 <- First Loop, User 3
Ref1,Value4 <- First Loop, User 4
Ref1,Value5 <- First Loop, User 5
Ref2,Value1 <- Second Loop, User 1
Ref2,Value2 <- Second Loop, User 2
Ref2,Value3 <- Second Loop, User 3
Ref2,Value4 <- Second Loop, User 4
Ref2,Value5 <- Second Loop, User 5
```

My thread Group setting with 2 threads with one request with parameters:

```
Name: Reference  Value:${Ref}
Name: Value      Value:${Value}
```

Is it possible to let the first thread get the first 5 lines and the second user get the next 5 lines that fits in the request?

Comment: Actually I face the problem is that the loop controller will make the thread group start getting the data from the csv data set begining. But what I want is the thread group will keep reading the csv data set in the next loop inside the loop controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to run both the threads in parallel with different data for each thread.

One of the way, is to have 2 thread groups and each have one request and one csv config with different file names and data. Then, run the thread-groups in parallel.

If you want 2 threads in sequence. Then, change the thread to 1 and run until EOF. This, I think is not your requirement.

I hope this help.

Comment: Actually, I want the thread group to keep reading the csv data set in the loop controller. But seems there are no way for me to achieve that. And finally I make some changes on the test plan to achieve my objective. :P

But still, if there are any advise about keeping the thread group to read the csv data set in the loop controller, please keep me update. Thanks :D